# Какие технологии взять для разработки онлайн шахмат?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, поиск-библиотек

Решил написать онлайн шахматы на JS, что б работало на nodeJS и статистику игрока(будет регистрация) сохраняло в MySQL.

Это должен быть страница где первым окном будет поле для ввода пароля и логина

После аутентификации должно быть игровое лобби где будет кнопка "начать игру" и "создать игру"

Если пользователь нажмет "создать" должна создаться комната, если "начать игру" то присоединиться до существующей

Мне было намного проще если б кто-нибудь подсказал в правильном выборе технологий и предоставил план ибо я частичный нуб =)

Comment: Для взаимодействия игроков в любом случае нужно изучать WebSocket. Регистрация и запись в БД в любом туториале Node.js. Ну а графику и анимацию на любой вкус, хоть Three.js для 3D шахмат.

Comment: Со столами ситуация похожа с покерными мини-турнирами Сит энд Гоу (Sit and Go) на двоих. Можете посмотреть по этой теме материалы.